# How To set UP Activities in Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".precus"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.yair.guessit.PRECUS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Customize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="FirstPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.yair.guessit.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

this is my manifest up there, and the app dont open .
can someone explain me how to set up the manifest with all the activites?
the precus is the first for now to open when the app open.
at the precus activity there is a intent that when the button get clicked its Customize activity.
why its not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line in your file

```
<action android:name="com.yair.guessit.PRECUS" />
```

to

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
```

then run it.

if it work fine. then mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: what is your first activity that you want to open

Comment: PRECUS , in precus i have a button that is pressed and open the customize activity

Comment: i dont know either... i dont run it on emulator its on my phone (HTC one s) and when i run it it just open for a milsec and then crashes...

Comment: so, error may be in your java code. Because java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect error come when your device not connected well and app take time in instalation..

Comment: and another error i've seen in your code is: 
Use R.id.tbGuessesCheckd in your onClick function

Comment: when i'v put the public its worked fine exept when i press the done button its crashes...

Comment: I think you got the NullPointerException when you click on the done button.. i'm right?

Comment: its dalvik.system.nativestart.main(Native Method)

Comment: error in your onCreate().  in this line..
in = getIntent();
after this line you extract the value from the intent..
but could not get..

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this,newActivity.class);
Bundle extra = new Bundle();
extra.putString("value_ID", value );
intent.putExtras(extra);
 Add this code from precus activity from your Customize class called and change the value that you want to send to your customize class.
startActivity(intent);

Comment: the last comment is for the precus class ?

Comment: yes 

And this is for the Customize class

Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
Album_ID = extra.getString("Album_ID");
use it in your onCreate method

Comment: im a little bi confused. can you give me what to put in precus in one comment and what to put in customize in other ? thanks !

Comment: in precus class
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this,newActivity.class); 
 Bundle extra = new Bundle(); 
  
 extra.putString("Guess", Guess);
 extra.putString("ifEnd", ifEnd);
 extra.putString("max", setRandoMax());
 extra.putString("min", setRandoMin());
 intent.putExtras(extra);

Comment: in Customize class in onCreate method 
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras(); 
 guess = extra.getString("Guess");
 ifEnd = extra.getString("ifEnd");
 max = extra.getString("max");
 min= extra.getString("min");

Comment: in precus class put them all in the onCreate method too ? cuz i did and its crash again

Comment: not in onCreat()..
Add that code from your customize class is called.

Comment: the code that i've given to you. in this i'm using the putString and getString change it according to your value...
means for the String value use putString and getString..
and for int value use putInt and getInt and 
for the bool value use putbool and getbool.. according to your variable type that you are using...

Comment: i did it already.. and i noticed that in customize code i used the getExtra in some other places so i changed it and it stil when i press done its crashes..

Answer (score 1):

Your application has all Activities with intent-filter **.Main**... Let only one to have this filter, in others - just delete intent-filteres like...

```
<activity
    android:name="FirstPage"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

Comment: ill try this , but what the .MAIN means ?

Comment: Main means, that this Activity will start first when you will start th app... Give a fiull error from LogCat...

Comment: Error which you show means that your droid is not connected or there some problems with adb driver or adb connection...